# Debugging tomcat filter chain in intellij

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, intellij-idea, servlet-filters

I deployed a `.war` file in tomcat. The `WEB-INF/web.xml` in the war file declares some filters but the running process seems to completely ignore the filters. :(

To debug this, I used intellij to remotely debug tomcat. (And can verify that the filter is indeed not called.) I can debug my own code without problems but intellij is not able to navigate me through the tomcat code (which is exactly the code building the filter chain.)

What do I need to do to be able to debug into the tomcat code?

Comment: You have to add Tomcat sources to your IntelliJ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051705/3511123 (check you are adding the proper one, of the version you use on the server)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Will happily accept it as a duplicate.